# Flask : What exactly is @app

Tags: python, flask, syntax

I am following [this](http://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-i-hello-world) **Flask** tutorial. We declare routes like `@app.route('/')` , but no variable in python can contain `@` character. 
I'm confused that what is `@app` and where it came from. Here's the code snippet :

```
from app import app

@app.route('/')
@app.route('/index')
def index():
    return "Hello, World!"
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It is a [decorator](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0318/). When decorated by `@app.route('/')` (which is a function), calling `index()` becomes the same as calling `app.route('/')(index)()`.

Here is [another link](https://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonDecorators) that can explain it, in the python wiki.

Answer (score 25):

The `@` is telling Python to *decorate* the function `index()` with the *decorator* defined in `app.route()`.

Basically, a decorator is a function that modifies the behaviour of another function. As a toy example, consider this.

```
def square(func):
    def inner(x):
        return func(x) ** 2
    return inner

@square
def dbl(x):
    return x * 2
```

Now - calling `dbl(10)` will return not `20`, as you'd expect but `400` (`20**2`) instead.

[This](http://simeonfranklin.com/blog/2012/jul/1/python-decorators-in-12-steps/) is a nice step-by-step. explanation of decorators.

Comment: This concept is also known as a closure. It's a nice way to add more functionality to a function without having to create a class.

Comment: @m1yag1 You just made me finally understand what a closure is useful for, by identification with Python's decorators, thanks ;)

Comment: Why is line 3 `return func(2) ** 2`, should it be `return func(x) ** 2` instead?